# Jq - converting JSON to another JSON format using jq

Tags: json, jq

I was using jqplay to playaround the format. somehow from some different format i was able to get to the below format. But now i want to change this format as below output. It basically i want to combine the object where both id's are same.

**'Input'**

```
[
  {
    "id": "7972",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-2G8AXE": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "true",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "true",
      }
    }
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "7972",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-4BR2P6B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      }
    }
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "6980",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-9BR289B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      }
    }
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "6980",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-8B0989B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "id": "7972",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-2G8AXE": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "true",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "true",
      },
       "1-4BR2P6B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "6980",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-9BR289B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      },
       "1-8B0989B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

please help me with this. I am looking to convert one json to another json format using some template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the sample input, the following invocation

```
< sample.json jq -n '
  [inputs[]]
  | group_by(.id)
  | map( reduce .[] as $x
           (.[0]|{id}; 
           .secondaryAddresses += ($x | .secondaryAddresses)))'
```

produces:

```
[
  {
    "id": "6980",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-9BR289B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false"
      },
      "1-8B0989B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "7972",
    "secondaryAddresses": {
      "1-2G8AXE": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "true",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "true"
      },
      "1-4BR2P6B": {
        "isDefaultBillingAddress": "false",
        "isDefaultShippingAddress": "false"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it worked..  '
  [inputs[]]
  | group_by(.id)
  | map( reduce .[] as $x
           (.[0]|{id}; 
           .secondaryAddresses += ($x | .secondaryAddresses)))' after adding this template... but will it be possible to explain me what are you doing here.. it will be very helpful

Comment: Assuming you have some familiarity with pipelines, it won't take long to read up on group_by, map, and reduce in the jq manual.  But it might help to know that you can add `debug` statements in the pipeline to see what's going on, just like `tee` in Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient solution, which happens also to be quite straightforward, though it comes at the the cost of a helper function.  Since this function is generic, it may be worth adding to your library of such functions.

```
def aggregate_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);
```

The following uses `inputs`, and accordingly must be used in conjunction with jq's `-n` command-line option:

```
aggregate_by( inputs[]; .id; .secondaryAddresses)
| map_values( add )
| to_entries
| map( {id: .key, secondaryAddresses: .value } )
```